# I have run a simple c code to print Hello World ; But It is not showing output in vs code in windows ; although I have minGW installed?

Tags: c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kENOv.png)

The c code to print Hello world is not showing output in vs code windows version
despite of having minGW installed in my computer.

Comment: Post code (text) here instead of external links.

Comment: Perhaps [this documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) about configuring VSCode with MinGW might be helpful to read?

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you have checked `Debug Console` yet.
There are few different ways outputs to be printed out,
via `Output`, `Debug Console` and `Terminal`,
Most of outputs are printed out on `Output`, but some of outputs are printed out on `Debug Console` when the code was running as a debugging.